# add an object or edit if exist (indexeddb)

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have this code and i can add or edit the object if exists, but the "for" finish before the function onsuccess is called, then the index "for" is bad.

How to pass the index onSuccess?

Help!!!

```
var active = dataBase.result;
var data = "";
var object = "";
var index = null;
var request;
$(".layers").promise().done(function () {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('layers');
     for (var i = 0; typeof (elements[i]) != 'undefined'; i++) {
        if (elements[i].getAttribute("src").split("/")[4] !== "alpha.png") {
        data = active.transaction([elements[i].getAttribute("src").split("/")[3]], "readwrite");
        object = data.objectStore(elements[i].getAttribute("src").split("/")[3]);
        index = object.index("by_Name");
        request = index.get(String(elements[i].getAttribute("src").split("/")[4] + "/" + elements[i].getAttribute("src").split("/")[6]));

        request.onsuccess = function (e) {
            var result = e.target.result;
            if (result === undefined) {
                var resultPut = object.put({
                    Name: String(elements[i].getAttribute("src").split("/")[4] + "/" + elements[i].getAttribute("src").split("/")[6]),
                    Count: 1,
                    Type: String(elements[i].getAttribute("src").split("/")[4])
                });
                resultPut.onerror = function (e) {
                    alert(resultPut.error.name + '\n\n' + resultPut.error.message);
                };
            } else {
                result.Count++;
                var requestUpdate = object.put(result);
                requestUpdate.onerror = function (event) {
                    alert(requestUpdate.error.name + '\n\n' + requestUpdate.error.message);
                };
            }
        }(event);
        }
    }
    alert("Finish");
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that, by the time the for has ended, the transactions with the object store are not. What you could try is to encapsulate the index like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    (function(myElement) {
        if (myElement.getAttribute("src").split("/")[4] !== "alpha.png") {
        ...
        }
    })(elements[i]);
}
```